# How to create a picker with toggle (for weight and height) in Angular?

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework, picker

This is what I would like to achieve. I am a little bit stuck so if anyone has any suggestions that would be amazing. Thanks a lot!

[image]

Here is my code so far, it's working but it's not exactly what I am looking for it it looks more complicated for the user. I would like to be able to toggle between metrics in the picker as in the picture above. My solution seems a little bit patched but I am new into coding and not sure how to approach this.

HTML

```
<ion-content class="ion-padding">
  <form [formGroup]="measurementsForm">
    <ion-grid>
      <ion-row>
        <ion-col>
          <div class="quiz-header">
            <ion-text class="small">QUESTION 2 OUT OF 10</ion-text>
            <h2>
              Now, let's talk about measurements
            </h2>
          </div>

          <ion-row class="quiz-choices">
            <ion-col>
              <ion-select
                [interfaceOptions]="customInterfaceOptions"
                formControlName="weightMeasurement"
                interface="action-sheet"
                placeholder="weight">
                <ion-select-option value="kg">kg</ion-select-option>
                <ion-select-option value="lbs">lbs</ion-select-option>
              </ion-select>
            </ion-col>

            <ion-col>
              <ion-input
                inputmode="numeric"
                formControlName="weightAmount"
                placeholder="amount"
                value="amount">
              </ion-input>
            </ion-col>
          </ion-row>

          <ion-row>
            <ion-col>
              <ion-select
                [interfaceOptions]="customInterfaceOptions"
                formControlName="heightMeasurement"
                interface="action-sheet"
                placeholder="height"
                (ionChange)="onSelectHeightMeasurement($event)">
                <ion-select-option value="cm">cm</ion-select-option>
                <ion-select-option value="ft">ft</ion-select-option>
              </ion-select>
            </ion-col>

            <ion-col *ngIf="!showFtInput">
              <ion-input
                inputmode="numeric"
                formControlName="heightAmountCm"
                placeholder="amount">
              </ion-input>
            </ion-col>
            <ion-col *ngIf="showFtInput">
              <ion-input
                formControlName="heightAmountFoot"
                placeholder="foot"
                inputmode="numeric">
              </ion-input>
            </ion-col>
            <ion-col *ngIf="showFtInput">
              <ion-input
                formControlName="heightAmountInch"
                placeholder="inch"
                inputmode="numeric">
              </ion-input>
            </ion-col>
          </ion-row>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>

      <ion-row class="quiz-buttons">
        <ion-col>
          <ion-button class="back-button" (click)="onNavigatetBack()"><</ion-button>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col>
          <ion-button
            class="next-button"
            [disabled]="!measurementsForm.valid"
            (click)="onSubmitStepTwo()"
            >Next
          </ion-button>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
  </form>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: We will not give you a code that do the job, here is for question or issue, we will be able to help you if you have tried something and if it doesn't work. But search elsewhere if you want the entire solution.

Comment: Hi! Yes, of course, I've tried something before. I'll post my code then. Thank you for the heads up!

Comment: Ok cool, so if I can I will help you :)